# Date Picker cant to set default date and min date at the same tim in jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to set default date and min date to my date picker using jquery.

This is my jquery code:

There have an ajax call before setting the date:

After that :

```
$('#'+categoryedit ).datepicker();
$('#'+categoryedit ).datepicker('setDate', valnew);
$( "#"+categoryedit ).datepicker( 'option', 'minDate', new Date(nextdate) );
```

Here `valnew` and `nextdate` have dates.The mindate worked ,but the default date not setting.

What is the problem in my code?

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it all when initializing the datepicker:

```
$('#'+categoryedit ).datepicker({
    setDate: valnew,
    minDate: new Date(nextdate)
});
```

Comment: following your code, the min date not working and setdate not any date